# I want every http url request in the device from any source to pass through my android app

Tags: android, http, vpn

I am developing an application in which I have to first examine the URL and then allow or disallow the HTTP request. So I wanted to know how can we do this in the Android Studio i.e. to examine every URL HTTP request in the device to pass through my android app so that I can analyze it.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please do some research and asks if you stuck anywhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Android VpnService](http://VpnService) (added in API 14.)
There is also a [Guide on it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn).

It probably also would not hurt to look at current opensource VPN projects for android: https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn